# How to map inputs inside each div to create array of hash using Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, hash

I have HTML as below

```
<div class="link-field">
  <div class="form-group assets-form">
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, Youtube Link">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, https://www.youtube.com/">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group assets-form">
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, Youtube Link">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, https://www.youtube.com/">
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried to iterate over each assets-form and create object like below

```
[
  {
    "link": "http://google.com/one",
    "description": "Link One"
  },
  {
    "link": "http://google.com/two",
    "description": "Link Two"
  }
]
```

using below function

```
$.map($('.assets-form'), function(field) {
  console.log(field)
});
```

Here I'm not able to construct the hash after looping over each div

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can launch the map function after form have been complete

in my sample i add a button to have to be click after input have been filled
you can recover field value by `$(field).find({fieldSelector})`

```js
function mapField() {
  let links = [];
  links = $.map($('.assets-form'), function(field) {
    return {
      link:$(field).find('#link').val(),
      description:$(field).find('#description').val(),
    }
  });

  console.log(links);
}
```

```html
<div class="link-field">
  <div class="form-group assets-form">
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, Youtube Link">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, https://www.youtube.com/">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group assets-form">
    <input type="text" name="description" id="description" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, Youtube Link">
    <input type="text" name="link" id="link" class="assets-input" placeholder="For example, https://www.youtube.com/">
  </div>
</div>
<button onclick="mapField()">map field</button>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```